# How to debug verify in moq?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, autofixture

I am using NPoco that comes with IDatabase class for the database call methods. I want to verify that the object going into the NPoco Insert method has the correct data(in the form of a domain object).

```
   public interface IUnitOfWorkProvider
    {
        IUnitOfWork GetUnitOfWork();
    }

    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable 
        {
            void Commit();
            IDatabase Db { get; }
            void SetOneTimeCommandTimeout(int timeout);
            void SetGlobalCommandTimeout(int timeout);
        }
    public interface IDatabase : IDatabaseQuery
    {
        IDbConnection Connection { get; }
        IDbTransaction Transaction { get; }

        void AbortTransaction();
        void BeginTransaction();
        void BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel? isolationLevel);
        void CompleteTransaction();
        IDataParameter CreateParameter();
        int Delete(object poco);
        int Delete<T>(object pocoOrPrimaryKey);
        int Delete<T>(Sql sql);
        int Delete<T>(string sql, params object[] args);
        int Delete(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco);
        int Delete(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco, object primaryKeyValue);
        void Dispose();
        Transaction GetTransaction();
        Transaction GetTransaction(IsolationLevel? isolationLevel);
        object Insert(object poco);
        object Insert(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco);
        object Insert(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, bool autoIncrement, object poco);
        void Save(object poco);
        void Save(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco);
        IDatabase SetTransaction(IDbTransaction tran);
        int Update(object poco);
        int Update<T>(Sql sql);
        int Update(object poco, IEnumerable<string> columns);
        int Update(object poco, object primaryKeyValue);
        int Update<T>(string sql, params object[] args);
        int Update(object poco, object primaryKeyValue, IEnumerable<string> columns);
        int Update(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco);
        int Update(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco, IEnumerable<string> columns);
        int Update(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco, object primaryKeyValue);
        int Update(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco, object primaryKeyValue, IEnumerable<string> columns);
    }

 // my test class file
 private IFixture fixture;
  private Mock<IUnitOfWork> unitOfWork;
  private MyService myService;
     private Mock<IDatabase> database; // new based on responses

    [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
 database = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IDatabase>>();// new based on responses 
            unitOfWork = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IUnitOfWork>>();
            myService = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyService>();
        }

        [Test]
        public MyTest()
        {       
              // fails
            unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.Db.Insert(It.IsAny<MyDomainObject>()));
            myService.CallMyMethod();
            unitOfWork.Verify(x => x.Db.Insert(It.IsAny<MyDomainObject>()));

            // fails
            unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.Db.Insert(It.IsAny<object>()));
            myService.CallMyMethod();
            unitOfWork.Verify(x => x.Db.Insert(It.IsAny<object>()));
// fails (this was a try based on responses)
 database.Setup(x => x.Insert(It.IsAny<object>()));       
 myService.CallMyMethod();        
 database.Verify(x => x.Insert(It.IsAny<object>()));

            // passes
            unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.Db.Insert(It.IsAny<object>()));
            myService.CallMyMethod();
            unitOfWork.Verify();
        }

public class MyDomainObject
{
   public void Id {get; set;}
}
```

The code being called(what should trigger the verify)

```
 using (var unitOfWork = unitOfWorkProvider.GetUnitOfWork())
            {
       MyDomainObject myDomain = anotherService.getMyDomain(DateTime.Now, 100);
       unitOfWork.Db.Insert(myDomain); 

}
```

Comment: your setups are not on mocks from what I can see - i.e. you could do `x.Db`, but the minute you dot another level in, you're outside of what a Setup expression can do - this is strongly corroborated by the fact that `Verify()` works [as you are callign `x.Db`]. But perhaps you've stripped too much out.

Comment: Like Ruben suspected, `IDatabase Db` gets *auto-mocked* and you set expectations on wrong objects. Normally, you would get null reference exceptions when doing `x => x.Db ...` bits (`Db` being null), but since you use AutoFixture, it passes silently. Your last example works only because there's no expectations on `unitOfWork` at all. I suggest you `Freeze` `IDatabase` and set expectations on it instead.

Comment: @RubenBartelink Moq creates whats called auto-mocking hierarchies (a.k.a. recursive mocks)  - so you can dot as many levels down as you want as long as they are virtual or abstract - so that Moq can proxy them

Comment: I tired freezing IDatabase but was not sure what to do with the frozen mock. when I just freeze it and do nothing with it the test still fails. When I was debugging IDatabase always seemed to have the same number(so I thought it was the same object)

Comment: @jimmy_keen - I updated my post with my newest tries but they all still don't work.

Comment: @glaucus Interesting to know. Glad I've never had enough of a Law of Demeter violation / need to test such an interaction to ever have to work this out before. BTW you taking into account that he's using AutoFixture w/ AutoMoqCustomization (I wasnt when I did my driveby comment earlier)?

Comment: I still have not clue why it is using a different object. The object looks the same to me but this is clearly the case. If I take the Idatabase out of the unit of work and just use that then it passes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your [SUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Under_Test) uses an IUnitOfWorkProvider to produce the IUnitOfWork:

```
using (var unitOfWork = unitOfWorkProvider.GetUnitOfWork())
{
    MyDomainObject myDomain = anotherService.getMyDomain(DateTime.Now, 100);
    unitOfWork.Db.Insert(myDomain); 
}
```

The IUnitOfWork instances that you are currently trying to mock are some other instances. They aren't produced by this IUnitOfWorkProvider.

Assuming that the IUnitOfWorkProvider is injected into your SUT, you should be able to Freeze that and go from there. Something like this ought to work:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
var uowProviderStub = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IUnitOfWorkProvider>>();
var uowMock = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Mock<IUnitOfWork>>();
var sut = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyService>();

uowProviderStub.Setup(p => p.GetUnitOfWork()).Returns(uowMock.Object);
uowMock
    .Setup(x => x.Db.Insert(It.IsAny<MyDomainObject>()))
    .Verifiable();

// etc.
```

That's all a bit of a bother, which is really the test trying to tell you that the [Law of Demeter violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) is not the best of designs...

Comment: Well how do you get around this Law of demeter? I mean it makes sense how my unit of work is setup.

Comment: To get rid of the IUnitOfWorkProvider you could just inject the IUnitOfWork directly into the service, and manage the lifetime of the service and UoW in your Composition Root.

Comment: @chobo2 Another approach is to sweep the issue under the carpet by using AutoFixture.xUnit and/or having a Customization that does the `uowProviderStub.Setup(p => p.GetUnitOfWork()).Returns(uowMock.Object);` bit behind the scenes. But please don't do that - go with Mark's proper solution

Comment: I still don't understand why it just does not use the same object. The reason I need the UnitOfWorkProvider is to make more unit of works. I may make several calls to methods in my service and each one needs it's own unit of work.

Comment: What sort of application are you building? Web app? Desktop app?

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your mocked calls verifiable

```
unitOfWork
    .Setup(x => x.Db.Insert(It.IsAny<MyDomainObject>()))
    .Verifiable();
```

Comment: Why? I tried that and it still fails. I still get Moq.MockException : 
Invocation was not performed on the mock: x => x.Db.Insert(It.IsAny<Object>())

Comment: MockException also contains what invocation was performed (if any), can you paste full exception text here?

Comment: Moq.MockException : 
Invocation was not performed on the mock: x => x.Db.Insert(It.IsAny<Object>())

at Moq.Mock.ThrowVerifyException(IProxyCall expected, Expression expression, Times times)
at Moq.Mock.VerifyCalls(Interceptor targetInterceptor, MethodCall expected, Expression expression, Times times)
at Moq.Mock.Verify[T,TResult](Mock mock, Expression`1 expression, Times times, String failMessage)
at Moq.Mock`1.Verify[TResult](Expression`1 expression, Times times)
at Tests.Services.ServiceTests.Test() in line 393